# Django, handle Response from external server

Tags: json, django, httprequest, httpresponse

The question is how can I handle HttpResponce from an external server?

The idea is that I send json data to an external server

(e.g search data `{'keyword': keyword, 'limit':limit, 'db':db}`)

`response = requests.post(url, json = userupload, headers=headers)`

after that I'm getting response from the server with json data

`return HttpResponse(response)`

It is on the screen, but as you can understand not in a good view for user...

So how can I add this data in a proper html table for example? (the best option is if I can print it out on the same page)

Comment: If you dont need a "middle man" why not use javascript? I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve, but this: http://docs.python-requests.org might help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to render the output of the post request which is in JSON format into a HTML file.

To do this, pass the json-encoded object from the view to the template:

**views.py:**

```
import json

def myview(request):
    obj = requests.post(url, json = userupload, headers=headers)
    return render_to_response("template.html", {"obj_as_json": json.dumps(obj.json())})
```

**template.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = {{ obj_as_json }};
    </script>
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/
In the django tutorial you learn how to render a response with html and context data.

If you are using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) you can do like:

```
response = requests.api.post(...
context = json.loads(response.json())
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

One of the big advanteges with json api's is that you can access it asynchronously with javascript. You should look in to that if you just want to render a response without calling your database to manipulate data from the json api.